# Mendeley desktop does not open in Fedora 31

Tags: fedora, mendeley

I am trying to run Mendeley desktop and, technically, the only thing that I should do is download the distribution for generic linux and run ./bin/mendeleydesktop

However, when I do that, the application never lauches. I tried running it with the verbose option to get more details, and I can't see any errors.

```sh
./mendeleydesktop --log-to-stderr --verbose-log

-- 2019-12-17 18:50:48.963 MendeleySqliteDatabase::prepareEncryptedDatabaseToBeOpened: Database /home/msarthur/.local/share/data/Mendeley Ltd./Mendeley Desktop/Settings.sqlite already using default db key 
-- 2019-12-17 18:50:48.971 MendeleySqliteDatabase::prepareEncryptedDatabaseToBeOpened: Database /home/msarthur/.local/share/data/Mendeley Ltd./Mendeley Desktop/Settings.sqlite already using default db key 
-- 2019-12-17 18:50:48.984 MendeleySqliteDatabase::prepareEncryptedDatabaseToBeOpened: Database /home/msarthur/.local/share/data/Mendeley Ltd./Mendeley Desktop/Settings.sqlite already using default db key 
-- 2019-12-17 18:50:48.985 MendeleySqliteDatabase::prepareEncryptedDatabaseToBeOpened: Database /home/msarthur/.local/share/data/Mendeley Ltd./Mendeley Desktop/Settings.sqlite already using default db key 
-- 2019-12-17 18:50:49.026 MendeleyApplication::execute: startup took 127 ms 
-- 2019-12-17 18:50:49.567 ConnectionTester::testDone: Platform: Linux-5.3 
-- 2019-12-17 18:50:49.567 ConnectionTester::testDone: Proxy Type: NoProxy 
-- 2019-12-17 18:50:49.568 ConnectionTester::testDone: Proxy Server:  
-- 2019-12-17 18:50:49.568 ConnectionTester::testDone: Proxy Port: 0 
-- 2019-12-17 18:50:49.568 ConnectionTester::testDone: Proxy User:  
-- 2019-12-17 18:50:49.568 ConnectionTester::testDone: Proxy Has Password: false 
-- 2019-12-17 18:50:49.568 ConnectionTester::testDone: verify depth 0 
-- 2019-12-17 18:50:49.568 ConnectionTester::testDone: verify mode 3 
-- 2019-12-17 18:50:49.568 ConnectionTester::testDone: cert 0 *.mendeley.com :07:01:c5:87:b7:3d:28:cd:37:ba:ab:25:09:75:00:cc:d4:66:35 is valid? 1 
-- 2019-12-17 18:50:49.568 ConnectionTester::testDone: cert 1 Trustwave Organization Validation SHA256 CA, Level 1 :92:b8:74:4f:71:ce:d0:e2:6c:72:a3:d8:d5:d9:25:b2 is valid? 1 
-- 2019-12-17 18:50:49.568 ConnectionTester::testDone: Connecting to api.mendeley.com (secure: 1, backend: Qt) - OK  Done (401) 
-- 2019-12-17 18:50:49.568 ConnectionTester::testDone: verify depth 0 
-- 2019-12-17 18:50:49.568 ConnectionTester::testDone: verify mode 3 
-- 2019-12-17 18:50:49.568 ConnectionTester::testDone: Connecting to s3.amazonaws.com (secure: 0, backend: Qt) - OK  Done (307) 
-- 2019-12-17 18:50:49.568 ConnectionTester::testDone: verify depth 0 
-- 2019-12-17 18:50:49.569 ConnectionTester::testDone: verify mode 3 
-- 2019-12-17 18:50:49.569 ConnectionTester::testDone: cert 0 s3.amazonaws.com :04:b2:eb:72:d4:41:39:bc:a3:7f:82:95:20:d5:7a:f0 is valid? 1 
-- 2019-12-17 18:50:49.569 ConnectionTester::testDone: cert 1 DigiCert Baltimore CA-2 G2 (www.digicert.com) :01:82:f8:09:8e:a2:e6:26:b9:1a:3b:27:84:1f:b9:af is valid? 1 
-- 2019-12-17 18:50:49.569 ConnectionTester::testDone: Connecting to s3.amazonaws.com (secure: 1, backend: Qt) - OK  Done (307)
```

Any insights?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is now an official distribution at: http://koji.rpmfusion.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=12107

This package builds and opens properly